# Retrieving value of count mongodb collection in a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count

I am trying to retrieve the value of records from a collection in Mongo DB

Here is my source.

```
exports.procc = function(req, res) {

        db.collection('search', function(err, collection) {
                    collection.count({'str':'car'},function(err, count) {
                       console.log(count+' records');//Prints 2 records
                       c=count;     
                    });
        });
        console.log('records= '+c);//print 0 records
 res.end();
};
```

The problem is that out of the callback prints the number of the register, but out of the callback prints 0 and I don't know how to save that value in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `db.collection` and `collection.count` are asynchronous methods, the `c` variable is getting set *after* the second `console.log` statement is executed.

So anything you want to do with `c` has to occur within the `collection.count` callback.

Comment: Ok, I will take it in account

Answer (score 0):

You code does not respect async nature of node.js IO.

```
exports.procc = function(req, res) {
        db.collection('search', function(err, collection) {
                    collection.count({'str':'car'},function(err, count) {
                       console.log('records= ' + count);//print 0 records
                       res.end();
                    });
        });
};
```